# pandas: return a value from a list column based on a condition in another list column

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements, subset

I have a large dataframe of list columns similar to the following, but more rows and columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'First':  [['First', 'value'],['second','value'],['third','value','is'],['fourth','value','is']],
'Second': [['adj','noun'],['adj','noun'],['adj','noun','verb'],['adj','noun','verb']]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second'])
```

i would like to return the value from the fist column if it equals a condition in the second column. so what i like is a third column that is like the following if the value in the second column equals 'adj'.

desired third column:

```
third column:
first
second
third
fourth
```

i have at least tried to filter the dataset for the rows containing the value 'adj' since my dataset is large, but do not know how to proceed:

```
df[['First','Second']][df['Second'].map(set(['adj']).issubset)]
```

Comment: If change `adj` to `verb` for test in sample data what is expected output?

Comment: thank you for the help. i had already filtered the ones that have adjectives, but your answer covers that too. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is always `adj` in each list get indices by `.index` and select by it value from second list:

```
df['new'] = [a[b.index('adj')] for a, b in df[['First','Second']].to_numpy()]
```

More general working if not exist `adj`:

```
df['new'] = [a[b.index('adj')] if 'adj' in b else None 
              for a, b in df[['First','Second']].to_numpy()]
```

Alternative with `apply`:

```
f = lambda x: x['First'][x['Second'].index('adj')] if 'adj' in x['Second'] else None
df['new'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)


print (df)
                 First             Second     new
0       [First, value]        [adj, noun]   First
1      [second, value]        [adj, noun]  second
2   [third, value, is]  [adj, noun, verb]   third
3  [fourth, value, is]  [adj, noun, verb]  fourth
```